# Uwp how to make splitview background acrylic blur

Tags: uwp, fluent-design

I am learning uwp developement and I am trying to make my splitview pane has acrylicbrush. As far as I know acrylic brush has two types. WindowAcrylic and Element Acrylic. In the default Windows 10 music app(Groove) the splitview menu has WindowsAcrylic when in compact mode and has ElementAcrylic when in opened mode. In the some tutorials they say when you set WindowsAcrylicBrush it automatically turns to elementAcrylicBrush when opened, but in my app that doesn't work like this.

Here is my splitview on compact mode
[image: Compact]
And Opened mode
[image: Opened]
But I am trying to make like this
[image: GrooveCompact]
[image: GrooveOpened]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the description about the different display Modes of the NavigationView, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview).

You have `Minimal`, `Compact` and `Expanded`. Depending on the display mode current state, the background is going to be painted differently, either with background acrylic or in-app acrylic.

For your situation, **you probably haven't reached the threshold defined so your app switches from Expanded to Compact**, and therefore we can still see the pane  being drawn side-by-side with the content and the background painted with background acrylic.

In case you want to define a different Window width from each the NavigationView enters the different display modes (*for your situation you might want your app to enter Compact Mode at an higher Minimum Width than it currently is*), checkout the following properties : `CompactModeThresholdWidth`
`ExpandedModeThresholdWidth`, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview)

Define the Acrylic Background resources for both `Background Acrylic` and `In-App Acrylic`, overriding the following NavigationView's Background Resources:

```
<media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#FF3333FF" TintOpacity="0.6" FallbackColor="#FF3333FF" />
<media:AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="#FF3333FF" TintOpacity="0.6" FallbackColor="#FF3333FF" />
```

With this you can use your own custom Background Resources, and you are not limited at using the Default background Acrylic and In-App Acrylic from the generic Theme Resources (`Light`, `Dark`,...).

You can see on this gif the app switching from Background Acrylic and In-App Acrylic depending on the Windows `Width`:

[image]

Comment: Actually I recently noticed that it doesn't work exactly as I want. What I want is in default pane mod and closed, it should show windows background, when opened it should show in-app background acrylic now. I hope I could explain. It works as I expected in expanded background mod.